# Comparing rows with datetime values against same table

Tags: sql, t-sql

First off, it might be helpful to mention that I don't have direct access to the database.  The software at my job has a built-in reporting feature that uses SQL, so it does limit some of the things I can do(as well as make it very difficult to do simple things).  Anyway, here is my scenario.  I have a table that contains rows such as this:

```
ClientVisit_ID   Client_ID   Time_In                 Time_Out
440222           12345       5/6/2019 9:45:00 AM     5/6/2019 9:59:00 AM
440195           12345       5/6/2019 10:00:00 AM    5/6/2019 12:30:00 PM
440523           54321       5/6/2019 11:45:00 AM    5/6/2019 12:59:00 PM
440775           54321       5/6/2019 12:58:00 PM    5/6/2019 1:30:00 PM
```

The first two rows are fine, The Time_In of row 2 is greater than the Time_Out of row 1.  I just want to see results like the 3rd and 4th rows, where the Time_In of row 4 is less than the Time_Out of row 3. These rows also may not be sequential in the database, but the Client_ID columns will match.

I tried using LAG, but I must be missing something in my query because it is only returning a few results and missing several rows I would want to see.  I've never used it before so I am pretty clueless.

```sql
SELECT CV1.*,
CV2.rev_timein
FROM ClientVisit AS CV1
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT
      *,
      CASE WHEN CVG.prev_rev_timeout >= rev_timein 
        AND CVG.prev_client_id = client_id
        THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS island_start_ind
  FROM
  (SELECT
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY client_id, rev_timein, rev_timeout) AS RN,
      clientvisit_id,
      client_id,
      rev_timein,
      rev_timeout,
      LAG(rev_timeout,1) OVER (ORDER BY client_id, rev_timein, rev_timeout) AS prev_rev_timeout,
      LAG(client_id,1) OVER (ORDER BY client_id, rev_timein, rev_timeout) AS prev_client_id
  FROM ClientVisit

  ) AS CVG) 
AS CV2 ON CV1.client_id = CV2.client_id AND 
             CV1.clientvisit_id != CV2.clientvisit_id AND
             CV1.rev_timein = CV2.rev_timein AND
             CV2.island_start_ind = 1
```

What would be the most ideal way to compare these rows to find overlapping times?  I also would like to see both rows that overlap, with the above code I was only getting just one row, not both (but as I mentioned it is missing several rows I know overlap).

Sorry for any formatting issues on this post, I've only asked a few questions on here.  Hopefully it's not too confusing.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to retrieve rows for the same client where the rev_timein is between the timein and timeout of another ClientVisit, this SQL should do it:

```
SELECT CV1.*, CV2.rev_time_in, CV2.rev_timeout
FROM ClientVisit AS CV1
INNER JOIN ClientVisit AS CV2
ON CV1.Client_ID = CV2.CLient_ID AND CV1.ClientVisit_ID <> CV2.ClientVisit_ID
WHERE CV2.rev_timein BETWEEN CV1.rev_timein and CV1.rev_timeout
OR CV2.rev_timeout BETWEEN CV1.rev_timein and CV1.rev_timeout
ORDER BY CV1.ClientVisit_ID

… 

OR, 

ORDER BY CV1.Client_ID, CV1.rev_timein
```